# Facing some issues while trying to Use DeepAR in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, deepar

I have copied the deep.ar files in the locations they have mentioned

I am getting this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':deepar_flutter:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':deepar_flutter:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find :deepar:.
     Required by:
         project :deepar_flutter
```

Does anyone knows how to solve them?

I have tried these steps:

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Delete `pubspec.lock`
3. Run `flutter pub cache clean`
4. Then try to do this:

You have to paste deepar.aar file into 2 different folders:
a. First In your flutter project as android/app/libs/deepar.aar.
b. Second ### %LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\deepar_flutter-\android\libs\deepar.aar

But nothing the issues continues any know how to fix that please help me.

I am trying to use deep ar in flutter application but am getting errors.